# How to get dynamic value of a variable declared in another file in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

In app.js file:

```
const tempStore = require("./tempStore.js");

setInterval(() => {
   tempStore.setTemp(1);
   console.log(tempStore.temp); // I expect this will log 1 then 2 then 3 so on...
}, 1000);
```

In tempStore.js file:

```
let temp = 0;

const setTemp = num => {
   temp += num;
}

module.exports = {
   temp: temp,
   setTemp: setTemp
}
```

I expect this line `console.log(tempStore.temp);` will give me a sequence of increasing number:

```
1
2
3
4
...
...
```

But it gives me this:

```
0
0
0
0
..
..
```

In other words always `0`.

I can find another way to get what I expect by modifying this code:

In app.js file:

```
const number = tempStore.setTemp(1); // store returned value in a constant
console.log(number); // show it
```

In tempStore.js file:

```
temp += num;
return temp; // return the result
```

But I prefer to get the number directly from `temp`, why this can't be done?

As far as I remember I can do this while coding in front-end development between .js file. But why I can't do this in NodeJS, what's wrong?

Comment: because the export is only the value at the time it is read. `export.temp` is not the same as  `temp` You should be using a getter.

Comment: @epascarello Could you provide some link to reference about that?

Comment: It is basic variable reference knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const store = {
   temp: temp,
   setTemp: setTemp
}

function setTemp(num) {
   store.temp += num;
}

module.exports = store;
```

The problem with your current approach is that the exported object's `temp` property is set to the value of `temp` when the object is created, and since inside the `setTemp` function the only change you make is to reassign `temp`, the exported object will not be mutated.

Is the same as this:

```js
let temp = 0;

const setTemp = num => {
   temp += num;
}

const store = {
   temp: temp,
   setTemp: setTemp
}

console.log("default", store.temp);

setTemp(10);

console.log("after change", store.temp);
```